# Adding Numbers to Postgres Database using RPostgres

Tags: r, postgresql, r-dbi

I have enjoyed working with the RPostgres (R package) for a while now and it works very well on most things. One thing I recently ran into is it seems to automatically convert numeric types in R into REAL in my Postgres database. The REAL type seems to be very imprecise so I would ideally like to cast my numerics into a type that can handle many more digits (nothing crazy but at least 10 or so). Anyone know how I can accomplish that? Here is an example before of adding numbers...

```
library(RPostgres)
library(DBI)
library(tibble)

con <- DBI::dbConnect(RPostgres::Postgres(),
                     host = 'localhost',
                     port = 5432,
                     user = 'test',
                     password = '')

test_tbl <- tibble::tibble(number_use =  434.94823992383445)

DBI::dbWriteTable(con, "test_tbl", test_tbl)
```

Comment: Try `dbWriteTable(con, "test_tbl", test_tbl, field.types = list(number_use = "numeric(10,10)"))`

Comment: Interesting, I got the following error but I will keep reading into the field.types parameter...
Error in connection_copy_data(conn@ptr, sql, value) : 
  COPY returned error: ERROR:  numeric field overflow
DETAIL:  A field with precision 10, scale 10 must round to an absolute value less than 1.
CONTEXT:  COPY test_tbl, line 1, column number_use: "434.948239923834"

Comment: I was able to get "numeric(12,8)" working though, seems the left side must be larger than the right?

Comment: I was just about to answer to that effect to test the precision and scale params. It appears *precision* is total number of digits before and after decimal point, with scale being number of needed decimal digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though part of the [DBI specifications](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DBI/DBI.pdf) that may or may not be integated into specific API, here being RPostgres, consider *field.types* argument, passing a named list of column names and types.

Below uses Postgres [NUMERIC(precision, scale)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/datatype-numeric.html) type (synonymous to DECIMAL) where  *precision* is total number of digits for value both before and after decimal point with *scale* being number of needed decimal digits.

```
# WITH NUMERIC(precision, scale)
dbWriteTable(con, "test_tbl", test_tbl, field.types=list(number_use="numeric(##,##)"))
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I could not figure out the field.types parameter. This should allow me to at least get hte numerical precision I want as long as I specify the field.types.

Comment: Sounds good. Yes, that argument may not be fully documented in RPostgres but are in DBI.